# Hide and show search bar of UISearchController on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

Since the recent update to iOS 13+ I am unable to hide/show the `UISearchController` using the following code, which was working perfectly on iOS 12-

```
if index == 2 {
   self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController()
} else {
   self.navigationItem.searchController = self.search
}
```

Is it possible to show/hide `UISearchController` in IOS13+ ?

Comment: Just set it to `nil` instead of `UISearchController()`

Comment: @henrik-dmg i did and when i do its ruin the UI when i set it back , its like add/remove , i want hide/show without effecting sub pages UI

Comment: It is not clear from where and when you are trying to do the above thing. Can you share more code with detail so that we could have some better insight?